# LM311 Current Sensing Switch

Tags: resistors, switches, current-measurement

I need to create a current sensing switch and am looking for ideas. I have very little experience with op amps / comparitors (as you'll see) but this seems to be the way to go.

I am monitoring 24VDC motor and if current is > 2.6A, I need to signal to a microcontroller to disable the motor.

I have a 175-R10-JBW (.1Ω) shunt resistor and an LM311 comparitor.

My testing shows that when the motor current = 2.6A, the voltage drop across the shunt resistor is ~.01v. When current is 1.3A the voltage drop is ~.005v.

My question is how do I use the LM311 to to state if "-" is .01v > than "+", send low output of LM311?

Of course I do not want to be shown exactly how to do this, just some direction on where to go. I've seen a lot of writing on current monitoring and op amp outputting an analog voltage proportional to motor current, that is just way overkill and would like to simplify.

Below is where I'm at and I know it's not close to where it needs to be. Any input would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: thank you for your comments below. With all the comments, I was able to determine it's best to go with one op amp feeding the micro. What I've been able to do is setup a differential amplifier with a gain of 2. And it works great. Motor < max amps = 1.3V (output of differential amplifier). Motor = max amps = > 2V output. Appreciate the feedback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need two op-amps.  One to give you the difference between the two volatges, and one to compare that voltage difference to a reference voltage.

Either that or read the voltage difference op-amp output with an ADC input on the microcontroller.

Also, you should investigate "High Side Current Sense Amplifiers" - they are chips specially designed for this purpose. They both calculate the voltage difference between two points and amplify it, and most often run off a lower voltage (3.3V or 5V) than the voltage level they are sensing at (say up to 60V).  I have used the AD8215 before now.

Comment: +1. And a microcontroller makes it easier on design, and less parts. Olin would love that suggestion haha. The end result is a microcontroller turning off the motor anyway so that's the best method. I think it's neat to have a second op-amp with a potentiometer to set the "Current trip" point but depends on the application really. May be a good project for the OP to learn how to use comparators and trimpots and whatnot, if they have the time/patience/leeway in their project